# Can you edit or add something to an NFT you already own?

Tags: nft

I wanted to know if this was possible. For example, if I own 1 NFT of Charmander and I then "mint" an evolve, is there a way to turn the first Charmander into Charmeleon or would this create another NFT?

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the contract.

Comment: I see. Is there a contract you can point me to that works like that? I am testing this and would really like to make it work.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a contract that does that. Something like that will need support from the server that serves the JSON file.